# I could take keyword as a common variable?

Tags: python, variables

I have a protobuf message, and the message has an variable, name is "pass", which is a keyword in python.

I get an error like :

"SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

while I assign an number to the "pass" argument:

```
msg.pass = 1
```

what should I do if I don't want to rename "pass" to "xxpass"? thank you.

Comment: For what its worth, the usual convention when you want to name a variable after a keyword is to append an underscore: `pass_`, `type_`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [setattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) which says:

> This is the counterpart of getattr(). The arguments are an object, a string and an arbitrary value. The string may name an existing attribute or a new attribute. The function assigns the value to the attribute, provided the object allows it. For example, setattr(x, 'foobar', 123) is equivalent to x.foobar = 123.

So in your case, you can use:

```
setattr(msg, 'pass', 1)
```

Note that to retrieve it, you're going to need its counterpart of `getattr`:

```
val = getattr(msg, 'pass')
```

Comment: Although you have to remember, the rules are generally there for a reason. Avoiding naming identifiers after reserved words is just a good practice to get into.